# CSS media query orientation change on desktop browser resize

Tags: css, orientation, media-queries

I'm not fully sure how this should work on desktops, but I'm pretty sure that when you resize the browser, the orientation should change (provided the height was bigger than the width and after resizing it's the other way round).

So that said, I have no idea why the following code only comes in effect on pageload.

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
  .slider-slide {
    background-size: auto 100% !important;
  }
}
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  .slider-slide {
    background-size: 100% auto !important;
  }
}
```

Basically what I want this code to do is to resize a background image based on the orientation. If I have the page resized properly on pageload, both work, but when I resize the window *on the fly*, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: you should use jquery on resize

Comment: @C-Link that is my last option, in case CSS doesn't work. Do you know for a fact that my CSS will not work in any way?

Comment: sorry, I don't know with css......

Comment: does `background-size:cover` (without mediaqueries) solve the issue?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan awesome! Yes it does. If you'd be kind enough to promote your comment to an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Fabrizio Calderan's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586339/css-media-query-orientation-change-on-desktop-browser-resize#comment29069282_19586339) is the best for the given use case, but if you need to detect changing to/from portrait and landscape, the answer to the original question is, yes, this will work.

You can see http://robertnyman.com/css3/media-queries/media-queries.html for a working sample.

The primary difference I see is that Robert used `screen` instead of `all`. So:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  ...
}
```

Beyond that there are probably some differences in browsers. Robert's solution worked for me in Chrome and FF. I am not sure about other browsers. (on a side note, there has to be a better caniuse than caniuse.com :) )